# Add UIImageView to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Was hoping someone could point out what is wrong with this.

My storyboard has a `UIScrollView` named `timelineScrollView` and a `UIImageView` named imageviewtest.

I am creating an image that is a simple straight line. If I add it to the `UIImageView` it displays fine. However if I add it to the `UIScrollView` then nothing displays.

How do I get it to display within the `UIScrollView`?

```
func drawingTest(){

    let drawing = DrawingHelper()
    let imageSize2 = CGSize(width: 100, height: 60)
    let fromPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)
    let toPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 50, y:0)


    imageviewtest.image = drawing.drawLine(fromPoint, toPoint: toPoint, imageSize: imageSize2)

    var imageView = UIImageView()
    var image = drawing.drawLine(fromPoint, toPoint: toPoint, imageSize: imageSize2)
    imageView.image = image;


    var scrollViewAreaSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 60)
    timelineScrollView.contentSize = scrollViewAreaSize
    timelineScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an appropriate frame to your image view or initialize UIImageView with your image:

```
var image = drawing.drawLine(fromPoint, toPoint: toPoint, imageSize: imageSize2)
var imageView = UIImageView(image:image)
```

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImageView/initWithImage:):

> This method adjusts the frame of the receiver to match the size of the
>   specified image.